# Problems with ajax load in safari and chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, playframework-2.2

I have a problem when running ajax requests, in **Safari** and **Chrome**, not in firefox

```
var doStuff = function(){
 callLoadingScreen();
 jsRoutes.controllers.SomeController.someServerSideMethod().ajax({
 //ajax stuff
 });
 closeLoadingScreen();
}
```

In safari and chrome, when doStuff() is called callLoadingScreen() method is skipped, but the ajax request is sent and only after the ajax request is completed than the method callLoadingScreen() is loaded.

In firefox everything works as its supposed to, but not in chrome and safari. Is this some play issue, or is it a jquery problem. I have tried a lot of fix, but none seem to work.Is there something I am missing, I have done this kind of loading before but don't remember having this issue.

Any help or feedback is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I allready had this issue. The only way I found to get it fixed is to  surround the ajax call with a test. Something like `if(loadingScreenLaunched == true){ ajax()...`. The ajax call wont be fired if the flag isn't set to true. Of course, you must affect this variable in the `callLoadingScreen()` function

Comment: Are you sure `callLoadingScreen()` really is skipped? I suggest to wrap it with `try ... catch` in order to find errors in callLoadingScreen.

Comment: If `callLoadingScreen()` acts asynchronously, you'll never have any guarantee that the three steps in your function are executed in the right order. If this is important, you should chain them by giving the next method to execute as argument to the predecessor.

Comment: @TCHdvlp sorry, it didn't work. And yes peter_the_oak, I tried the try-catch and it doesn't seem to have any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code is not running an ajax call with `async: false` **which you should never do**, it should *not work as-is* on any browser.

You need to wait for the Ajax call to complete before calling `closeLoadingScreen`:

e.g.

```
var doStuff = function(){
 callLoadingScreen();
 jsRoutes.controllers.SomeController.someServerSideMethod().ajax({
 //ajax stuff
       complete: function(){
           closeLoadingScreen();
       }
 });
}
```

In your example, it is doing this:

```
 callLoadingScreen();
 closeLoadingScreen();
 // Get response from Async Ajax call here sometime much later!
```

If you want to use promises instead, try it this way:

```
var doStuff = function(){
   callLoadingScreen();
   jsRoutes.controllers.SomeController.someServerSideMethod().ajax({
      //ajax stuff
   }).then(closeLoadingScreen);
}
```

Comment: What about creating a deferred in `callLoadingScreen()` and do something like `callLoadingScreen().then(ajax()).then(closeLoadingScreen());`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie trying you solution now.

Comment: @TCHdvlp@: That is effectively the same thing (only more complicated to introduce promises for a newbie). I will add as an option.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @TrueBlueAussie, it seems I have been doing things the wrong way all along, `async:false` and calling after coming methods not in `complete:{} or success:{}`

Comment: `async: false` is the worst possible hack to avoid doing things properly :)

Comment: @TCHdvlp@: Added a promise version. Note: your example was calling the close immediately (and they would usually want the load to run in parallel to the Ajax call).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Ho I see. when the ajax starts, it fires the second `then`. So you were right by putting the close function in the ajax callback.